# Failed to use fstab for folder mount

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to mount my G drive (in WSL) under `/code`. However it fails with the following config and message:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /         ext4  defaults        0 0

/mnt/g                /code   none  defaults,bind 0 0
```

```
[ 5159.133867] init: (1) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:655: /bin/mount failed with status 0x
[ 5159.133870] 2000
[ 5159.133876] init: (1) ERROR: ConfigMountFsTab:2152: Processing fstab with mount -a failed.
[ 5159.143122] FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
[ 5159.143124] FS-Cache: O-cookie c=0000000092644cce [p=000000007ba11936 fl=222 nc=0 na=1]
[ 5159.143125] FS-Cache: O-cookie d=00000000f69d3d22 n=000000004319b7e9
[ 5159.143125] FS-Cache: O-key=[10] '34323935343533313833'
[ 5159.143128] FS-Cache: N-cookie c=000000000be0e99c [p=000000007ba11936 fl=2 nc=0 na=1]
[ 5159.143129] FS-Cache: N-cookie d=00000000f69d3d22 n=000000005622393b
[ 5159.143129] FS-Cache: N-key=[10] '34323935343533313833'
[ 5159.146589] FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected
[ 5159.146592] FS-Cache: O-cookie c=0000000092644cce [p=000000007ba11936 fl=222 nc=0 na=1]
[ 5159.146592] FS-Cache: O-cookie d=00000000f69d3d22 n=000000004319b7e9
[ 5159.146593] FS-Cache: O-key=[10] '34323935343533313833'
[ 5159.146595] FS-Cache: N-cookie c=0000000095f81e84 [p=000000007ba11936 fl=2 nc=0 na=1]
[ 5159.146595] FS-Cache: N-cookie d=00000000f69d3d22 n=0000000024b2120e
[ 5159.146596] FS-Cache: N-key=[10] '34323935343533313833'
```

Is the mount in `/mnt` done somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can mount only drive partitions into directories.
Partitions are available in `/dev/` directory. You can list them all with command `lsblk`.

Your second line in fstab contains: `/mnt/g     /code`. Why?

Maybe you just want to create a symbolic link from `/mnt/g` to `/code`?

It that case it would be: `ln -s /mnt/g /code`

Comment: Thanks for the `lsblk` tip. No, I need a full bind mount, link is not enough